# sort javascript numbered keys object by property values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to sort following object by `Value`

```
var myObj = {"1": {"Value": 40}, "2": {"Value": 10}, "3": {"Value": 30}, "4": {"Value": 20}};
```

I tried to use sort to get keys of desired order but while making new object using it is the problem for me. I tried below method to sort:

```
var myObj = {"1": {"Value": 40}, "2": {"Value": 10}, "3": {"Value": 30}, "4": {"Value": 20}};
sorted = Object.keys(myObj).sort((a,b) => myObj[a].Value - myObj[b].Value).reduce((_sortedObj, key) => ({
   ..._sortedObj, 
   [key]: myObj[key]
 }), {});
console.log(sorted);
```

Can somebody point out where am I making mistake?

Comment: Object properties have no defined order. If you need order, convert to an array. All browers sort numerical properties by their numerical order irrespective of insertion order.

Comment: You can't sort object properties.  Do you want an array?

Comment: what is your expected result? In Array form ? Object form ?

Comment: @Dean: I expect it in object form

Comment: I'd love to provide a possible alternative, but this question has been closed.  `Object.keys(myObj).map(function(v){return Object.assign({'Index':v},myObj[v])}).sort(function(a,b){return a.Value>b.Value?1:-1})` yields a sorted array of objects contain index and value properties => ` [{Index: "2", Value: 10}, {Index: "4", Value: 20}, {Index: "3", Value: 30}, {Index: "1", Value: 40}]`

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript Objects are not Ordered like arrays. They are key value
>   pairs and you can access any value in constant time by just it's key.

If you want them to be ordered then you can iterate over the properties of your object and push them in array and sort them in the order you want.

you can get something like this.

```
[{"Value": 10}, {"Value": 20}, {"Value": 30}, {"Value": 40}];
```

This is an **array of Objects** where each element is an object containing a key-value pair.